# How to replace only a certain part of a list?

Tags: python, list

How do I replace apple in the beginning of each string in the list to orange?

Here is what I have tried:

```
appleList = ['apple_00', 'apple_01', 'apple_02', 'apple_03']

appleList = ['orange' if 'apple' in appleList]

print appleList
```

**Output:** `['apple_00', 'apple_01', 'apple_02', 'apple_03']`

**Desired Output:** `['orange_00', 'orange_01', 'orange_02', 'orange_03']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `replace` method to modify the strings inside the list:

```
>>> my_list = ['Apple_00', 'Apple_01', 'Apple_02', 'Apple_03']
>>> print([s.replace('Apple', 'Orange') for s in my_list])
```

this will print

```
['Orange_00', 'Orange_01', 'Orange_02', 'Orange_03']
```

As a side note, you should really use lowercase names for variables per [Python Style Guide - PEP08](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` when an item contains `Apple`.

This does it:

```
r = [x.replace('Apple', 'Orange') for x in Register]

print(r)
# ['Orange_00', 'Orange_01', 'Orange_02', 'Orange_03']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if certain elements in the list are the string `'Apple'`, which is obviously never `True`. you can do it like this:

```
Register = ['Apple_00', 'Apple_01', 'Apple_02', 'Apple_03']
New_Register = []

for entry in Register:
    New_Register.append(entry.replace('Apple', 'Orange'))

print Register
print New_Register
```

Or you just use a list comprehension:

```
Register = ['Apple_00', 'Apple_01', 'Apple_02', 'Apple_03']
Register = [x.replace('Apple', 'Orange') for x in Register]

print Register
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Selcuk - I was myself a bit confused about the uppercase variable name, which is normally used for classes. I use only lowercase variable names with underscore...